# Menu placed wrong

Tags: css

Here is what my header is supposed to look like:

[image]

And here is what it looks like sometimes:

[image]

As you can see the menu to the right is placed wrong sometimes, does someone have a clue how to fix this?

By sometimes I mean when I refresh the page by F5 or CTRL + F5.

Here are my codes:

HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="content_navigation">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="img/logo.png" style="margin-top: 15px;" /></a>
        <a href="register.php"><div class="main-menu">Register</div></a>
        <a href="login.php"><div class="main-menu">Login</div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content_navigation {
    width: 960px;
    height: 60px;
    margin:0px auto;
    color: black;
}

#navigation{
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #232323;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    font-size: 20px;
}

.main-menu {
    min-width: 20px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: right;
}
.main-menu:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, by sometimes I mean when I refresh the page by F5 or CTRL + F5. When I go to the page by clicking on the "login" button it shows the menu as it's supposed to.

Comment: Did you try floating links ? perhaps `#navigation a { float:right; } #navigation a:first-child { float:left; } `

Comment: It seems like I am the only one having problems with this in Chrome, I will leave it as it is and hope that others don't see this :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your  css to

```
   .content_navigation {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
     margin:0px auto;
    float:left;

}

#navigation{
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #232323;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    font-size: 20px;
    position:relative;
     float:left;

}

.main-menu {



    color:Red;
    font-size: 14px;
   float:right;
 position:relative;
   padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;



}
.main-menu:hover {
    color: white;
    cursor:pointer

}
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gQ3LY/)

Comment: Hmm that didn't work :( When I navigate on the page by clicking on the logo, login and register everything is at the right position but as soon as I refresh the page, the menu moves down.

Comment: @user3049858: now check it..!!

Comment: I did try that but it didn't work :( I am using the same CSS as you but I didn't se the width to 100% and float to left on .content_navigation because it's supposed to center everything in a box that is 960px wide. Could you see my website and try to refersh the page: http://likenation.com/social/login.php

EDIT: I have also noticed that this only happesn in Chrome when you refresh the page.

Comment: i can't find any problem in chrome..!! are you sure?

Comment: i didn't find any problem in chrome and firefox..!! did you set my css code to the site ?

Comment: Then something is wrong on my end because I am having this problem only in Chrome, I will however leave it as it. Thanks for your help!